# Can i make a switch a socket?

Tags: switch, socket

I have a switch in my kitchen that switches on/off a socket underneath the cupboards for a washing machine. I have now moved the washing machine and would like to make the switch a socket so I can plug something in on top of the worktop.

Is this a simple job, Can I just wire up a socket into the existing back wires of the switch or is there more too it than that?

Comment: There's more to it than that. Can you take a few pictures of the switch box, inside, that you talking about?  Turn off power before removing any covers or the switch and don't disconnect any wires.

Comment: Two problems. Light branches are 15A, outlets 20A. A new breaker _could_ fix that if the wiring is thick enough. Also, you might not have a neutral available at the box, though there's some odds that it's simply tucked behind the box in an accessible place. Provide you have neutral access and a 20A breaker and sufficient wiring, then it's simple.

Comment: @dandavis -- not necessarily

Comment: @dandavis It was already circuit for washing machine, not lighting, so in theory should be 20A. And if not? Still might be OK (not sure). But neutral is a **big** potential issue.

Comment: Where on this planet *are* you, anyway? That's an important question here

Comment: What else is on this circuit? Do you already have 2 circuits for kitchen countertops?

Comment: It really depends as @jack said it may be just 2 wires in there and be switching the hot only without knowing what wires are there it is a total guess the answer can go from absolutely yes to well not easy.  As it is a switch now the 2 circuit question is not relevant to the national electric code used in the US and some other countries.